# Difficulty in generating time series in R for my data set

Tags: r, time-series

So I am trying to generate time series for my dataset in R but finding difficulty in doing so. My dataset has two columns- one for date and other for price of a material. Now there are many dates which don't have price and hence are not in the dataset. Data is roughly for a year. NOw i am finding difficulty in setting the frequency and start time for the time series. Is there any way to set the start as per the dataset and time series automatically incorporates the missing data points.

Comment: when you say 'automatically incorporates the missing data points', do you mean you want the missing dates to appear in your series, with NA values for the corresponding prices? in any case, do not use `ts` if your data is not regularly spaced - see the `xts` or `zoo` packages instead.

Comment: Would try that then...thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the following is for a dataframe df with two columns called "date" and "price".
This will create missing dates and fill the missing prices for those dates as the preceding price. You can change `fill('price')` to fill with other specified values.

```
library(tidyverse)
  df<-df %>%
    complete(date = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by="day")) %>%
    fill('price')
```

Comment: glad to help. if it works for you, could you mark it solved?